# How to write a regular expression for my string?

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression for `QR8.4_Z4J25` in shell script? How can i do it?

Is this correct?

```
[QR][0-9][.][0-9][_][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9]
```

Comment: Is this correct? wrong. `[QR]` matches Q or R not QR

Comment: Do you know what brackets mean in regular expressions? `[QR]` means either a `Q` or an `R`, so it cannot possibly match the substring `QR`.

Comment: It's very simple and possibly doesn't require RegEx. Now you have two problems.

Answer (score 1):

It's obviously wrong because it'll only match `Q8.4_Z4J25` or `R8.4_Z4J25`, but not `QR8.4_Z4J25`

A bracket matches any **one character** specified, so you'd like to write:

```
[Q][R][0-9][.][0-9][_][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9]
```

You don't need to use brackets for a single character, though, so it can be simplified to

```
QR[0-9]\.[0-9]_[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9]
```

Be sure to escape the dot if it's outside of a bracket because it would otherwise match **any** single character.

in case you want to match `QR9.1_8A9YK` as well, you should change it to

```
QR[0-9]\.[0-9]_[A-Z0-9]\{5\}
```

If you're using Extented Regular Expression, usually by supplying an option `-E` to the tool you're using, then you shouldn't escape the braces:

```
QR[0-9]\.[0-9]_[A-Z0-9]{5}
```

Comment: You shouldn't escape the `{` or `}` characters.

Comment: @Sovuit In BRE you must, in ERE you mustn't.

Answer (score -1):

Square brackets in regular expressions denote a collection of characters.

- `[MX_5]` will match one character that is `M`, `X` `_` or `5`.
- `[0-9]` will match one character that is between `0` and `9`.
- `[a-z]` will match one character that is between lowercase `a` and `z`.

Notice the pattern? The square brackets match a single character. In order to match multiple characters they need to be followed by a `+` or `*` or `{}` to denote how many of those characters it should match.

However, in your case, you just want to match the actual letters `QR` in that order, so simply don't use square brackets.

```
QR[0-9]\.[0-9]_[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9]
```

The same goes for characters like the underscore which are always in the same place. Note that the `.` was escaped with a `\` because it has a special meaning in regex.

Going back to matching multiple characters with square brackets, if the order of the last 5 characters doesn't matter, you can further reduce your expression using a single square bracket and a `{}` to match all your trailing characters after the underscore.

```
QR[0-9]\.[0-9]_[A-Z0-9]{5}
```

Comment: BRE or ERE? I escaped braces for BRE.

Comment: @iBug what are you talking about? You don't need to escape braces in regex.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards): *BRE and ERE work together. ERE adds `?`, `+`, and `|`, and it removes the need **to escape the metacharacters `()` and `{}`**, which are **required in BRE.***

Comment: You can test it with `grep -G` and `grep -E` and see the differences.